# Why do I get this: "TypeError: myfunc() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I'm trying to do is when the dictionary `this_dict` is called it should execute `myfunc` where it checks for the number of times the function is called and changes the output in that respect.

Although whenever I execute it I get the error `TypeError: myfunc() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`. I'm not sure why this happens.

```
class A(object):
    this_dict = {}

    def get_response(self, request):
        response = self.this_dict[request]
        if callable(response):
            response = response(self, request)

        print response

class B(A):
    b= 'b'
    c= 'c'
    tries = 1
    
    def myfunc(self):
        self.tries += 1
        if self.tries < 3:
            return self.b
        else:
            return self.c
        
    this_dict = {
        'a': myfunc(),
        'd': 'some_string1',
        'e': 'some_string2',
        'f': 'some_string3',
    }

b = B()
b.get_response('a')
```

Comment: `my_func` is an ***instance method***. You call it in the class level without passing any specific instance. In other words, the method expects an argument `self` which is not passed. I would say that the error is quite clear about that...

Comment: You mean to say I should pass as `myfunc(self)`, in `this_dict()`?

Comment: No, because there is no `self` in the ***class*** level. Personally I don't understand what `this_dict` is for

Comment: ahh, so I've to define `def myfunc(self, request)` eventhough `request` is not used for `myfunc()`. I get it now! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I myself not sure I fully understand, but it looks like you edited a solution (judging by its description). Please don't edit the question with solutions. If that's the case, please rollback the question to its original form and post your solution as an answer. Although I don't understand, I am happy I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct way to do it.
When defining `def myfunc()` I need to include the `self` and `request` as arguments to this method.
It works for me like this:

```
class A(object):
    this_dict = {}

    def get_response(self, request):
        response = self.this_dict[request]
        if callable(response):
            response = response(self, request)

        print response

class B(A):
    b= 'b'
    c= 'c'
    tries = 1
    
    def myfunc(self, request):
        self.tries += 1
        if self.tries < 3:
            return self.b
        else:
            return self.c
        
    this_dict = {
        'a': myfunc,
        'd': 'some_string1',
        'e': 'some_string2',
        'f': 'some_string3',
    }

b = B()
b.get_response('a')
```